# Linux readw and readl endianness

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

May anyone please explain the endianness of returned values by `readw` and `readl`. I am currently using PowerPC arch.

Thanks and Best Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"readw" and "readl" return the value of the underlying architecture.

As it happens, a PowerPC can be *either* big- or little endian.

AFAIK, most Linux implementations run PPC in big-endian mode.

Answer (score 1):

1. readw/readl read using HOST-endian (i.e. same endianess as your arch)
2. Return value itself naturally has no endianess, when you store it to memory it would be stored, again, using host-endian
3. You wouldn't normally need to keep in mind actual host endianess (there is API and macroses to free you from this need), moreover, if you need to, your code is probably incorrect and/or not portable

Answer (score 0):

The important bit to understand is that these functions always assume your device (or wherever you're performing I/O) wants to see *little endian* presentation of the value. See include/asm-generic/io.h (Linux v6.0.6):

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later */
...

/*
 * {read,write}{b,w,l,q}() access little endian memory and return result in
 * native endianness.
 */
```

The parameters and return values for those functions are expected to be in *native endianness* (ie., whatever the CPU happens to be), while the format on the device/memory being accessed is taken to be *little endian*.

So before/after calling those functions, you can conveniently do whatever arithmetic is necessary on your variables using the CPU (as they're stored in native endian, and you don't have to know which one that is). But the device will *always* see those values converted to *little endian* regardless of the host (native) endianness.

See eg. `writel()` converting from native to LE, and `readl()` converting from LE to native:

```
/* SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later */
...

static inline void writel(u32 value, volatile void __iomem *addr)
{
    ...
    __raw_writel((u32 __force)__cpu_to_le32(value), addr);
    ...
}

static inline u32 readl(const volatile void __iomem *addr)
{
    ...
    val = __le32_to_cpu((__le32 __force)__raw_readl(addr));
    ...
}
```